# Use a variable from a protected override void in another class of the C# project

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, drag

Normally I use properties in order to use a variable from another class in a class.
It then looks like the following code, which servers as an example:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
namespace ConsoleApplication1  
{  
    class Employee  
    {  
        private int _EmpID = 1001;  
        private string _EmpName;  
        public int EmpID  
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return _EmpID;  
            }  
        }  
        public string EmpName  
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return _EmpName;  
            }  
            set  
            {  
                _EmpName = "Smith";  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    class AcessEmployee  
    {  
        static void Main()  
        {  
            Employee objEmployee = new Employee();  
            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID: " + objEmployee.EmpID);  
            Console.WriteLine("Employee old Name: " + objEmployee.EmpName);  
            objEmployee.EmpName = "Dyne Smith";  
            Console.WriteLine("Employee New Name: " + objEmployee.EmpName);  
            Console.ReadLine();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Now, I have an protected override void in a public class called "DragCanvas_ : Canvas".
It looks as follows:

```
public class DragCanvas_ : Canvas 

{




protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);

        var positionTransform = this.ElementBeingDragged.TransformToAncestor(this);
        var areaPosition = positionTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));


        // Reset the field whether the left or right mouse button was 
        // released, in case a context menu was opened on the drag element.
        this.ElementBeingDragged = null;
        var _left = areaPosition.X;
        var _top = areaPosition.Y;
        Console.WriteLine(areaPosition.X);
        Console.WriteLine(areaPosition.Y);
        
    }
    
}
```

I want to use the two variables "_left" and "_top" in another class of the C# project. The general properties approach (see code 1) does not seem to work with a "protected override void".

Comment: *"My properties approach does not seem to work"* - what approach? Can you show? You probably used `private` modifier for members in base class, use `protected` instead.

Comment: @Sinatr Oh sorry, I should have written the "general properties approach" instead of "my properties approach". I just edited my post in regard to this. I tried to use the first code, i.e. the general approach for using the values of variables of a class in another class of the project as a template for using the two variables (the coordinates (the variable _left as left margin in regard to the canvas and the variable _top as the top margin relative to the canvas) in another class of my C# project. A "protected override void" seems to need another approach. I don't know. I am quite new to OOP.

Comment: [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers). Recommended to read everything (4 minutes).

Answer (score 3):

You have only declared local variables. You cannot use them outside the overridden function.

```
var _left = areaPosition.X;
var _top = areaPosition.Y;
```

You should move them up to class level with the `public` modifier in order to make them accessible in other classes.

```
public class DragCanvas_ : Canvas 

{
    public double Left {get; set;}
    public double Top {get; set;}
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
.....
    Left = areaPosition.X;
    Top = areaPosition.Y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was definitely helpful at first (the other cs-file at least recognizes the variable from my DragCanvas_.cs.file) and I implemented everything you suggested in my code, but if I want to let the two variables write to the console in the other C#-file of the whole C#-Project, they are not written inside the console, when I put `Console.WriteLine(Left);` 
and `Console.WriteLine(Top)` inside a newly created C#-File, which has the same namespace as DragCanvas_.cs.

Comment: Only in the DragCanvas_-class, i.e. in the DragCanvas_.cs-file the two variables are shown in the console with `Console.WriteLine(Left);` and `ConsoleWriteLine(Top);`.

Comment: The newly created C#-file, i.e. new class looks as follows: 
`using System;` 
`using System.Collections.Generic;`
`using System.Linq;`
`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`
`using System.Text;`
`using System.Threading.Tasks;`

`namespace ABC` 
`{`
 `class Class01 : DragCanvas_` 
 `{`
  `Console.WriteLine(Top);` 
  `Console.WriteLine(Left);` 
 `}`
`}`

Comment: Inside the DragCanvas_.cs, i.e. inside the DragCanvas_ class it works. What could be the reason for this? I guess I create a subclass of DragCanvas_ with `class Class01 : DragCanvas`, but otherwise the Variable from the DragCanvas_ class is not known in the new cs-file, so the setter and getter method does not work here.

Comment: You need to override the base function in the new canvas class `Class01`. Try that!

Comment: thanks for the hint! As I am quite new to C# and OOP in general I read this article (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overriding/) about overrding a base function.

Comment: How is it now? If it works, you can accept the answer.

Comment: I am not that fast :D. I write back in 10 min. If it was the solution I mark your answer as the solution of my problem.

Comment: Take your time!

Comment: Yes:). I still have to understand my linked article, which descripes your suggested overriding method.

Comment: I still read the article 10 min and then I have to go home and at home I continue to work on it. I'll report back, if your answer was the solution or not.

Comment: I tried it with the base keyword, i.e. the base keyword specifies the calling of base-class constructor from derived class when derived class instances are created. And combined it with your answer. However, unfortunately it still does not work :(.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can use "syntactic sugar" in properties to avoid creating unnecessary variables in your code. C # is smart enough and will itself generate a local variable that it will access.

That is, instead of:

```
private int _EmpID = 1001;   
public int EmpID  
{  
   get  
   {  
      return _EmpID;  
   }  
}
```

It turns out one line

```
public int EmpId { get; private set; } = 1001;
```

Secondly, read more about the visibility of variables. When you create an object in a nested code block in a method, then this object will be visible only in that code block in the method.

If you want to use variables outside the method, then there are two solutions:

1. Declare variables as public fields of a class

```
public class DragCanvas_ : Canvas 
{
   public decimal Left { get; set; } //I don't know exactly what type of areaPosition.X
   public decimal Right {get; set; }

   protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
      ... // your code in this method
      Left = areaPosition.X;
      Top = areaPosition.Y;
    }
    
}
```

2. Use modifier `out` to return value from method. For now, you will not need to declare variables in the class. If you do not go into details, then variables are created at the stage of calling the method and are passed immediately as parameters

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e, out decimal Left, out decimal Top)
{
   ... // your code in this method
   Left = areaPosition.X;
   Top = areaPosition.Y;        
}
```

In this case, it won't help second option, unless of course you call the method programmatically in code. Therefore, this is to improve your knowledge.

Comment: The auto-property translation would simply be `public int EmpId { get; } = 1001;` - there is no private setter in the OP's code.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I have explicitly added the private setter, because that would provide accessibility which is equivalent to the non-readonly private field. We do however not know whether OP ever modified the field, but obviously an Employee's ID must not be fixed.

Comment: @Claus Stolz: Your second example does not work for OnPreviewMouseUp (Compiling error code CS0115). Your first example does not give a compiling error, but does not do what I want, due to the `protected override`-access modifier. I only get the values of the variables, which I made public with getter and setter inside the DragCanvas_.cs class and not in the MainWindow.xaml.cs-class, where I need the values of the two variables.